# need ideas for making Angular ui-grid columnDefs as generic as possible

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

We have several REST endpoints and it returns a csv formatted file with different number of columns on each file. I hardcoded the columnDefs for each on my AngularJS application. So far it's working great.

It will become a nightmare once new csv file is introduced. It also becomes a night,are when an existing csv file gets modified and I'm not informed.

How can we make it as generic as possible meaning it will adjust based on response? I would like to get rid of hardcoding columnDefs everytime there is a change.

Comment: I do actually get the column defs along with data from server side, so i have made a directive for the grid and it works for multiple sources without a single line change anywhere :)

Comment: Can you please share a plunker HarishR?

Comment: its a c# code, most of it, client side is just getting gidOptions and setting it. cant make plunker of c# code

Comment: What does your CSV look like?  Does it have headers?  Can you give a sample?  Assuming that it does have headers, you can easily create an array of columnDefs on a fly, package as JSON, and send to the client.  I will post you a solution that shows basic client-side principle of dynamic comumnDefs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can create columnDefs via an array of objects that can be loaded from server along with the data:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <title>Demo Grid</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="gridController">
            <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ng-init="GetGridData(urlList)">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="Scripts/ng/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/ng-grid/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Scripts/ng-grid/ui-grid.min.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid']);

            app.controller("gridController", ["$scope", "$http", "$q", function ($scope, $http, $q)
            {
                $scope.urlList = "YourURL";

                function fnGetList(url)
                {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http.get(url)
                        .success(function (data)
                        {
                            deferred.resolve(data);
                        })
                        .error(function (errorMessage)
                        {
                            alert(errorMessage);
                            deferred.reject;
                        });
                    return deferred.promise;
                };

                function fnParseContent(content)
                {
                    //  Assuming your content.data and content.columnDefs contains well-formed JSON

                    if (content.columnDefs !== undefined)
                    {
                        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = JSON.parse(content.columnDefs);
                    }

                    if (content.data !== undefined)
                    {
                        $scope.loadData = JSON.parse(content.data);
                    }
                }

                $scope.GetGridData = function (url)
                {
                    //console.log("In GetGridData: " + "Getting the data");
                    $scope.loadData = undefined;

                    //  Test Only - Uncomment for client-side test only
                    //  This is how your columnDefs should look like coming from the server

                    //var content =
                    //{
                    //    columnDefs: JSON.stringify(
                    //        [
                    //            { field: 'UserName', name: 'User' },
                    //            { field: 'Email', name: 'e-mail' }
                    //        ]),
                    //    data: JSON.stringify(
                    //        [
                    //                {
                    //                    "UserName": "Joe.Doe",
                    //                    "Email": "Joe.Doe@myWeb.com"
                    //                },
                    //                {
                    //                    "UserName": "Jane.Doe",
                    //                    "Email": "Jane.Doe@myWeb.com"
                    //                },
                    //        ])
                    //}
                    //fnParseContent(content);
                    //return;

                    //  End of Test Only block

                    fnGetList(url).then(fnParseContent(content));
                };

                $scope.gridOptions =
                {
                    data: 'loadData',
                };
            }
            ]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this will help you with your solution.

Cheers.

Comment: I did it differently and code is way smaller
`    .then(function(csvdata) { $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.length = 0; for (var i=0; i<csvdata.split("\n")[0].split(",").length; i++) {
                                    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({ name : JSON.parse(csvdata.split("\n")[0].split(",")[i]), enableSorting: true })
                                }

How do we paste code in comments? It's not properly quoted.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem.  The easiest way to do it is to add your comment as an answer, and mark it as the solution.  If you can add a Plunkr or JSFiddle along with it - so much the better.  Cheers.

Comment: I found a page earlier saying to prepend `code` on our code. Not sure if it will work

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it

```
RestFactory.all('csvexport').get($scope.gdEndpointPath, {
    reportresourceid : $rootScope.downloadToken,
}).then(function(csvdata) {
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.length = 0;
    $scope.myData = csvToJson(csvdata);
    $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.myData;

    for (var i = 0; i < csvdata.split("\n")[0].split(",").length; i++) {
        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({ name : JSON.parse(csvdata.split("\n")[0].split(",")[i]), enableSorting: true })
    }
}, function(err) {
       ....... 
});
```